# Problem after installing pycharm-"failed to create interpreter"

Tags: snap, pycharm

I installed Pycharm using command: `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`

After installation it says to execute the following

```
/tmp/tmpa8b_tv67pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setup.py install
```

which on running on terminal

```
sys:bash: /tmp/tmpa8b_tv67pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setup.py: No such file or directory
```

[image]

What to do now?

Comment: The error in screenshot is different than what you mentioned in body, Please run `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` and see if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue after new installation on Pycharm. Running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

as suggested in [Kulfy's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184913/problem-after-installing-pycharm-failed-to-create-interpreter/1207985#comment1979886_1184913) and [ratherunsaid's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184913/problem-after-installing-pycharm-failed-to-create-interpreter/1207985#comment1980553_1184919) comments solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to try installing PyCharm from Ubuntu Software Center. 
Also if you could attach a screenshot of the error you get would help understand where the setup.py file is searched for.

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: Install the packages two packages below:
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
sudo apt install python3-pip / sudo apt install python-pip
For python3 & python2 respectively.